# Program control goes back to servlet from Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

We had to display certain text from backend to the webpage without page refresh, we used Javascript/ajax for the same, it was successful for one of the link so we tried the same logic somewhere else here the print happens in the webpage but we get a blank screen with message "Served at: /" within few seconds. 
The webpage and the required text from backend disappears for a blank screen within few seconds.

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ViewCubeConfigBookingsCube').click(function() {
  var Stream = "BookingsCubeStage";
   $.ajax({
type:'POST',    
url: "ViewCurrentCubeConfig",
data: {Stream: Stream},
cache: false,
success: function(result) {
/*result_without_path = result.replace("Served at: /FINBI_E2E ","");*/
$("#data").html(result);
$("#data").html(result).slideDown('fast');
 }
});
});
});
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
    String Stream=request.getParameter("Stream");
    String ConfigXMLPath=UtilLib.getEnvVar("CubeConfigXMLFilePath");
    String ConfigDetails="";
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    @SuppressWarnings({ })
    HashMap CurrentConfigDetails =new HashMap();
    System.out.println("The Stream is: "+Stream);
    ViewCurrentCubeConfig_Implementation ViewCurrCubeConfig =new ViewCurrentCubeConfig_Implementation();
    CurrentConfigDetails=ViewCurrCubeConfig.ViewCurrentCubeConfig(ConfigXMLPath,Stream);

      // Get a set of the entries
      Set set = CurrentConfigDetails.entrySet();
      // Get an iterator
      Iterator i = set.iterator();
      // Display elements

      while(i.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
         //System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
         //System.out.println(me.getValue());
         ConfigDetails=ConfigDetails+(me.getKey() + ": ");
         ConfigDetails=ConfigDetails+" "+(me.getValue());
         ConfigDetails=ConfigDetails+"\n";  
      }
     // System.out.println("Config detailas are as : "+ConfigDetails);
      try{
          PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
              out.print(ConfigDetails);
      }
      catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      } }
```

[image: Devtools Search results]

Before click:
[image]

Config output:

> Config detailas are as : Year:  FY15
>   DataBase:  ZZZZZ
>   Application:  YYYYY
>   NumberOfMonths:  5
>   ServerName:  XXXXX
>   MonthStartingFrom:  Aug

HTML:

```
 <a href="" id="ViewCubeConfigBookingsCube">View Current Config  Details</a><br>
 <div id="showBookingsCubeCurrConfig"></div>
```

Comment: Do you see any text/html response from your Servlet for your AJAX call ? You can check that in `DevTools (F12) - Network Tab - Search for ViewCurrentCubeConfig`.

Comment: @Arkantos: Sorry i could not find the window you mentioned, however in eclipse console I could not find any error message.

Comment: DevTools will be in your browser :)

Comment: @Arkantos: My bad, updated with the screen shot, "No matches found"

Comment: I see that you are firing AJAX call inside some click handler. Is this screen shot taken after the click ?

Comment: Probably it would be helpful to see the HTML and a full dump of the output in `ConfigDetails`

Comment: @Arkantos: Yes it is taken after click

Comment: @AxelAmthor: Update the HTML and config details

Comment: Put an alert inside your click handler and in your success callback and check if both are coming

Comment: @Arkantos: Thanks for the suggestion arkantos, here's what i did and it resolved the issue: 1) put the JQuery at the very last of the script file. 2) Restarted Eclipse and gave build project from start.